# Topological Quantum Field Theories

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian, topological-field-theory

I've asked this on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701100/topological-quantum-field-theories), but with no avail. So, I decided to ask it here.

I was wondering about the following after reading the Wikipedia article on TQFTs.

It is said that TQFTs have vanishing Hamiltonians $\hat{\mathcal{H}}$. Firstly, I would like to ask:

> Why is this so?

Secondly, consider the Schroedinger equation:
$$i\hbar\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\Psi=\hat{\mathcal{H}}\Psi=0$$
So, there are no dynamics or propagation. This leads to my second question:

> What does one mean by "nontrivial dynamics/propagation" (as mentioned in the Wikipedia article)?

I've understood the TQFT must be invariant under time reparameterizations, the reason being pretty obvious.

Thank you!